# Convert Sandcastle Help File Builder Output (Web site) to MediaWiki format

Tags: mediawiki, sandcastle, shfb

I need to

1. convert my Sandcastle Help File
   Builder (SHFB) output that is a Web
   site (HTML) to Media wiki format
2. Find a way to transfer/include the
   converted pages directly into the
   MediaWiki we have set up.

Any ideas? we have over 1000 pages of HTML files inthe Website (output of SHFB).

I thought of using a html2wiki converter ..I could think of looking around for a script to convert those 1000 pages into wiki format... that could take care of (1).

But I would still be left with the block in the last bit of the pipeline - how to feed converted pages directly into the Wiki?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Help Server. It allows to publish .CHM / .HxS produced by any tool (including Sandcastle) on the web and provides [URL-based integration API](http://help.x-tensive.com/).

We use MediaWiki as well. [A set of templates for it](http://wiki.dataobjects.net/index.php?title=Code_templates) allows us to create links to class reference shared by Help Server. Some examples of such links can be found right on that page.

Note that [DataObjects.Net Help](http://help.dataobjects.net/) web site is running on Help Server 2.X, but the newest one is 3.X ([example web site is here](http://help.x-tensive.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

I did some work with ingesting existing material from several sites into a comprehensive Wiki. It did not involve Sandcastle, but if you're dealing with HTML it shouldn't matter much. **html2wiki** extensions are out there, and from what I have read they can solve a lot of problems. I needed a little more control over each node in the DOM, so i used [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It's in PHP and was easily dropped into Mediawiki's includes.

For creating the new pages, I ended up writing a small script that uses Mediawiki's Article class, specifically the [doEdit function](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classArticle.html#44882bb1533f07bf67baca3e65821bb3). this allows you to create new articles programatically, without user interaction. Of course, you'd want to be careful with this... The last thing you need is to create 1000 pages that are no good and have to be deleted. But perhaps this will help get you going.