# How to autodoc .Net Google code projects?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I know how to generate html documentation using Sandcastle and similar tools. But if I want to host the project on Google code, how can I easily publish the documentation straight into the Google project Wiki pages?

I can see the SVN repository has a wiki folder which I assume maps to the project Wiki pages and I guess I can make a build step to build the documentation from the autodoc tags. But is there some tool that generates wiki compatible format from the code documentation tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, you're right about the SVN repository...**

You're correct in assuming that the 'wiki' folder is there to contain any/all wiki documents that are viewable on Google Code. If you want to see for yourself, create a wiki page on the site and browse the source to see what I mean.

**Second, it doesn't look like there's an 'official solution' to generating .wiki files from the autodoc tags but that doesn't mean you're the only one trying**

[Here's an approach where the Sandcastle files are used to populate a wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276334/convert-sandcastle-help-file-builder-output-web-site-to-mediawiki-format).

[Here's an approach to extract the comments themselves from the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759714/extracting-doc-comments-from-c-source-file).